# Consulta MySQL where 'al menos' contenga uno de los valores

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un **buscador** en mi pag web en la que se puede buscar **usuarios** o **#etiquetas**. Este esta formado por un `form` alojado en el `menubar`, este **buscador**. Este buscador esta formado simplemente por un `input`
 y por ub `button`. Para buscar una **etiqueta** simplemente se coloca un `#` antes de la palabra a buscar y para buscar un **usuario** pues sin `#`. 
Ejemplo:

**Ejemplo buscar usuario** : `pepito` 
**Ejemplo buscar etiqueta** : `#programacion`

Aqui dejo mi **barmenu** el cual contiene el `form` **buscador**

```
<nav  class=" tema_principal navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light mobile-nofixed tema_principal">
  <a style="padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;" class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="perfil.php">Mi perfil <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Mensajes
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="crear_mensaje.php">Crear mensaje</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="ver_mis_mensajes.php">Ver mis mensajes</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="POST" action="buscador.php">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="buscador" aria-label="Search" placeholder="#etiqueta1 usuario">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </form>
    <a style="margin: 5px; height: 40px;" class="nav-link btn btn-danger" href="procesos/logout.php">Salir</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

En concreto este es el buscador :

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="POST" action="buscador.php">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="buscador" aria-label="Search" placeholder="#etiqueta1 usuario">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Buscar</button>
    </form>
```

El fichero al que llama el `action` del `form` es el siguiente:

```
<?php 


    include_once 'conexion.php';
    include_once "controllers/mensaje.php";

    $mensaje_controller = new Mensaje();


    $buscador = $_POST['buscador'];
    $esUsuario;

        if (substr($buscador, 0, 1) === '#') { 
            //etiqueta

            $buscador = str_replace("#","",$buscador);
            $result = $mensaje_controller->verMensajesContengaEtiqueta($buscador);
            $esUsuario = false;     
        }
        else{
            //usuario               
            $mensaje_controller= new Mensaje();
            $result = $mensaje_controller->verMensajesUsuario($buscador);
            $esUsuario = true;
        }   


         if ($result) {

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                  $mensajes[] = [
                        'id' => $row['mensaje_id'],
                        'titulo' => $row['mensaje_titulo'],
                        'contenido' => $row['mensaje_contenido'],
                        'createAt' => $row['mensaje_createAt'],
                        'creador' => $row['mensaje_creador'],
                        'url_img' =>     $row['mensaje_url_img'],
                        'etiquetas'=> [
                            'ids'=> explode('|', $row['etiquetas_ids']),
                            'nombres'=> explode('|', $row['etiquetas_nombres'])
                        ]
                    ];
            }


         }


         //var_dump($mensajes);




     ?>
```

En este fichero **buscador.php** hace un poco como de **organizador previo a la busqueda**, es decir, mira si tiene `#`, si es que tiene llama a la **funcion que busca etiquetas** de mi **controlador**.Si **no** tiene `#` llama a la funcion que **busca usuarios**.

Bueno, pues para conseguir el funcionamiento de mi **buscador** estoy haciendo dos **consultas**:

La **primera consulta** (*esta funcion seria si busca por **usuario***) debe obtener todos los mensajes de un usuario, esta **funcion bien:**

```
     SELECT 
                          mensajes.id AS 'mensaje_id',
                          mensajes.titulo AS 'mensaje_titulo',
                          mensajes.contenido AS 'mensaje_contenido',
                          mensajes.createAt AS 'mensaje_createAt',
                          usuarios.usuario AS 'mensaje_creador',
                          mensajes.url_img AS 'mensaje_url_img',
                          GROUP_CONCAT(etiquetas.id SEPARATOR '|' ) AS 'etiquetas_ids',
                          GROUP_CONCAT(etiquetas.nombre SEPARATOR '|') AS 'etiquetas_nombres'

                     FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes 

                    INNER JOIN mensajes ON mensajes.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_mensaje  
                    INNER JOIN etiquetas ON etiquetas.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta
                    INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = mensajes.creador
                    WHERE usuarios.usuario = 'jose'

                    GROUP BY mensajes.id
                    ORDER BY mensajes.id DESC
```

La **segunda consulta** (*esta funcion seria si busca por **#etiqueta***) la he hecho siguiendo el mismo **patron** de la **primera consulta**

```
        SELECT 
               mensajes.id AS 'mensaje_id',
               mensajes.titulo AS 'mensaje_titulo',
               mensajes.contenido AS 'mensaje_contenido',
               mensajes.createAt AS 'mensaje_createAt',
               usuarios.usuario AS 'mensaje_creador',
               mensajes.url_img AS 'mensaje_url_img',
               GROUP_CONCAT(etiquetas.id SEPARATOR '|' ) AS 'etiquetas_ids',
               GROUP_CONCAT(etiquetas.nombre SEPARATOR '|') AS 'etiquetas_nombres'
            FROM 
                etiquetas_en_mensajes 
           INNER JOIN mensajes ON mensajes.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_mensaje  
           INNER JOIN etiquetas ON etiquetas.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta
           INNER JOIN usuarios ON usuarios.id = mensajes.creador
            WHERE 
                    etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta  IN  (
                      SELECT 
                            etiquetas.id 
                        FROM 
                            etiquetas
                        WHERE 
                            etiquetas.nombre = 'nombreEtiqueta'
                    )
            GROUP BY mensajes.id
            ORDER BY mensajes.id DESC
```

Esta ultima **no lo hace mal del todo**,  pero solo me tra la etiqueta que le digo que busque y deberia traer **todas las demas etiquetas** si es que las hay, asociadas al mismo mensaje

**Por ejemplo:**

**Primera consulta**: en las etiquetas(que es donde esta la problematica) tendria el valor `etiqueta_1|etiqueta_2|etiqueta_3|etiqueta_4`. Eso seria lo **correcto**. 

**Segunda consulta:** Pero en mi segunda consulta que busco **por nombreEtiqueta** me sale lo siguiente: `soloNombreEtiquetaPorlaQueBuscoHabiendoAParteDeEstaMasQueNoLasMuestra` (En la **subconsulta** hago uso de `IN` porque esta me va a devolver una **coleccion de datos**)

La **segunda consulta** deberia decir: Buscame todos los mensajes donde **al menos** tengan la **etiqueta** `X` (pero traeme las demas etiquetas asociadas al mensaje tambien, la **etiqueta** `X` es simplemente el criterio de busqueda)

El **diagrama** de BD esta en esta otra pregunta:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es muy complicado entenderte sin un diagrama de tu base, pero la query  SELECT 
                            etiquetas.id 
                        FROM 
                            etiquetas
                        WHERE 
                            etiquetas.nombre = 'nombreEtiqueta' Solo trae un registro, estas seguro que querias ver esa tabla?

Comment: Si, disculpa, no me habia fijado que no la subi. Ya esta actualizada la pregunta con el **DER**  de mi base de datos.Gracias

Comment: un diagrama de base de datos, es un DER ;). UML es otra cosa ;). Ahora volviendo al punto, mi teoria es correcta. Si queres traer mas de una etiqueta ademas de esa, tenes que ir a una tabla que tenga todas las etiquetas.. porque tu subquery, solo va a traer un id de tu etiqueta si lo pones asi. Probalo por separado y vas a ver que trae un solo registro. Por eso, siempre es mejor resolver el query por pedazos e ir viendo que traer

Comment: De acuerdo, ya he actualizado el comentario disculpa. Eso he hecho, primero pruebo la subconsulta, pero me trae solo un valor

Comment: Y ahi esta tu problema. Que es lo que queres ue traiga? Y de donde?

Comment: ¿Quizá haciendo un `LEFT JOIN` en alguna de las tablas? El problema es que, como dice @gbianchi, la pregunta no es muy clara. ¿Qué tal si asumes que tu solución podría no ser la mejor, y antes de lanzar el código, dedicas el primer párrafo a explicar lo que quieres hacer?, así quizá se te podría sugerir una forma más óptima de resolver el problema. Sea como sea, es necesario entender claramente lo que tienes y lo que quieres para poder ayudarte de la mejor manera.

Comment: Claro, voy a editar la pregunta . Como yo lo plantee no es el camino que tiene que ser si o si, sino como lo vi mas claro. Respecto al contenido siempre intento poner lo minimo de extension que albergue la maxima informacion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya tienes vinculada la tabla `etiquetas` mediante `INNER JOIN etiquetas...` así que no te hace falta un `where` tan "complicado", quita:

```
          WHERE etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta  IN  (
              SELECT 
                    etiquetas.id 
                FROM 
                    etiquetas
                WHERE 
                    etiquetas.nombre = 'nombreEtiqueta'
            )
```

y lo cambias por :

```
WHERE etiquetas.nombre LIKE '%nombreEtiqueta%'
```

> El operador `IN` ,además de lento, tiene limitaciones respecto al
>   tamaño de la lista donde buscar, evítalo en la medida de lo posible.
>
> ***"The number of values in the IN list is only limited by the max_allowed_packet value"***
>
> **Fuente:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Revisa también [búsqueda por patrón](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

---

(edición)

Para no perder el resto de etiquetas, debido a la restricción del `WHERE` añadimos otra vinculación a la tabla `etiquetas` pero esta vez con un alias para poder referenciarla de forma unívoca en el `SELECT`:

(edición 2)

Verificado, funciona con `INNER JOIN`, se añade :

```
INNER JOIN etiquetas_en_mensajes AS em2 ON mensajes.id = em2.id_mensaje      
INNER JOIN etiquetas AS e2 ON e2.id = em2.id_etiqueta
```

La consulta quedaría así:

```
   SELECT 
          mensajes.*,
          GROUP_CONCAT(e2.id SEPARATOR '|' ) AS 'etiquetas_ids',
          GROUP_CONCAT(e2.nombre SEPARATOR '|') AS 'etiquetas_nombres'     
     FROM mensajes 
    INNER JOIN etiquetas_en_mensajes ON mensajes.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_mensaje  
    INNER JOIN etiquetas AS e  ON e.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta    
    INNER JOIN etiquetas_en_mensajes AS em2 ON mensajes.id = em2.id_mensaje      
    INNER JOIN etiquetas AS e2 ON e2.id = em2.id_etiqueta    
    WHERE e.nombre LIKE '%nombreEtiqueta%'           
    GROUP BY mensajes.id
    ORDER BY mensajes.id DES
```

**Verificación:**  https://rextester.com/IDGT38023

Comment: El problema es que me busca los mensajes que contenga esa etiqueta, eso **bien** pero me devuelve el mensaje como si la unica etiqueta que tuviera es la que busco, a veces pasara si, pero otras veces tendra mas etiquetas y esas no son reflejadas en el **output** de la consulta

Comment: ok, edito la respuesta

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias

Comment: Muchas gracias, pero aun sigue mostrando la etiqueta por la que buscas. Como podriamos hacer ?

Comment: editado y verificado

Comment: justo lo habia solucionado yo, pero veo que con muchas mas lineas y menos optimo, esta vez si lo lograstes !

Comment: lo que no entiendo son los alias para que los pones

Comment: Si no pones alias no podrías hacer referencia, de forma única, a una tabla vinculada dos veces, como puedes ver hago dos `INNER JOIN etiquetas` uno lo uso para el `SELECT` y otra para el  `WHERE`, sin alias es imposible indicarle a cual me refiero en cada caso.

Comment: Pero no entiendo porque tiene que ser una referencia de forma unica, es una referencia no? ya esta.

Comment: Es una referencia condicionada, con el `WHERE e.nombre LIKE '%nombreEtiqueta%'`  lo que le dices a la base de datos es: "Muestra **solo** las etiquetas con nombre que contenga *nombreEtiqueta*" y sin embargo en el `GROUP_CONCAT(e2.nombre...`  necesitas **todos** los nombres, sin ser afectado por el filtrado del `WHERE`

Comment: aah ya entendi, perfecto. Muchas gracias por tu atencion de verdad.